# Implement a callback mechanism that notifies for INSERTS/UPDATES

Tags: java, sql-server, triggers

I have an SQL server and I would like to get a callback each time new data was added or updated to some tables.

My initial thoughts are:

1. I would like to avoid using solutions like log shipping, linked servers, transactional replication, change tracking, change-data-capture, integration service because I want to be as less invasive to the server as possible.
2. Create a trigger that somehow sends callback requests to my Java service.

Can I achieve such a thing using a simple trigger like that:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger ON my_table
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
 -- call something that notifies my Java service
END
```

Comment: A trigger that notified something is going to be highly invasive - you want to avoid that at all costs.

Comment: If you are talking about security or something like that, this is not a concern, how can a trigger be more invasive compared to let's say change-data-capture.? Also, what are my alternatives for achieving the described pipeline (change) -> (?) -> (java service)?

Comment: Because the last thing you want to do is make calls to outside services from inside a trigger, which is right in the middle of a SQL transaction... that will make any inserts or updates slow and unpredictable. I would have an external service polling the database for changes. Or have the trigger put an event in a table that is read by the external service.

Comment: `have the trigger put an event in a table that is read by the external service` This seems like a promising solution, but then how would I monitor this table for changes polling seems the only option.

Comment: I've never found a good solution to polling - it's a necessary evil at some point.

Comment: If you want please elaborate more on that approach on an answer so I can close this question. eg how to efficiently poll the DB with java etc

Comment: I would write a small windows service. But that's a topic in its own right depending on your architecture.

Comment: In C# there is `SqlDependency` not sure if Java has equivalent

Comment: The best approach between synchronous that blocks data and asynchronous that can be late regarding the treatment you will have in your java service, is to use SERVICE BROKER or NOTIFICATION SERVICES that integrate an asynchronous way of communication...

Comment: @ThanosM I think we can do this once I was looking for the same issue I found this article helpful   https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/jjdev/calling-Java-from-PL-SQL.html#GUID-499ABE6B-4391-43C8-A527-74A6C7B0A0FF

Comment: @AshishMishra calling a stored procedure from Java is not what I asked, but thank you for your time.

Comment: @SQLpro can you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: @ThanosM , you can call the procedure from the trigger that would call a notify method inside a notif class in java, isn't it what you want?

Comment: SERVICE BROKER provides dedicated stacks (user internal tables) that you will feed with the results of triggers. Then a "listen" loop constituted by a procedure that you must write, will take the first row and "digest" it to proceed on whatever you want. For this purpose, and to be read only once, and then destroy, the row will be acquired by the special T-SQL command RECEIVE that do simultanously a SELCT combine to a DELETE...